# How to simplify the following Script to make it easier to write HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used the below code for toggling between selection. But the Script I have used is simple so I need to write more in HTML to hide the other tabs as you can see in the code. Help me with the Script to simplify the HTML part.

```js
function showStuff(id) {
  var id1 = id.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(id1).classList.add('active');
}

function hideStuff(id) {
  var id1 = id.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById(id1).classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
div.container {
  padding: 7px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ol>
      <li id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff('tabs-1'); hideStuff('tabs-2'); hideStuff('tabs-3');hideStuff('tabs-4'); hideStuff('tabs-5');hideStuff('tabs-6'); hideStuff('tabs-7');hideStuff('tabs-8'); hideStuff('tabs-9');hideStuff('tabs-10'); hideStuff('tabs-11');hideStuff('tabs-12'); hideStuff('tabs-13');hideStuff('tabs-14'); hideStuff('tabs-15');hideStuff('tabs-16');hideStuff('tabs-17');hideStuff('tabs-18');hideStuff('tabs-19');">selet A</li>
      <li id="tabs2" onclick="hideStuff('tabs-1'); showStuff('tabs-2'); hideStuff('tabs-3');hideStuff('tabs-4'); hideStuff('tabs-5');hideStuff('tabs-6'); hideStuff('tabs-7');hideStuff('tabs-8'); hideStuff('tabs-9');hideStuff('tabs-10'); hideStuff('tabs-11');hideStuff('tabs-12'); hideStuff('tabs-13');hideStuff('tabs-14'); hideStuff('tabs-15');hideStuff('tabs-16');hideStuff('tabs-17');hideStuff('tabs-18');hideStuff('tabs-19');">select B</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 1%; "></div>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <h1>A is selected</h1>
    <textarea onclick="this.focus(); this.select();" readonly="readonly">
this is example and A is selected
</textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2" style="display : none">
    <h1>B is selected:</h1>
    <textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly">
Another example for b is selected

</textarea></div>
</body>
```

Also, I need to get the textarea content from a text file (stored with in server)or by any other means so I can avoid that lengthy part to be added with in the code. Is there a way to replace textarea with text file??

Comment: You can simplify using jquery toggleClass(), https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/, and some CSS classes

Comment: Why do you need to use a regular expression on the passed in string?

Comment: You can also use some data-attributes to tie the tabs with the headers easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Show and hide you can hide and unhide using same function.

Suppose you have :

```
<ol>
    <li id="tabs1" class="tabheader" onclick="setActive()" data-id="tab1">selet A</li>
    <li id="tabs2" class="tabheader" onclick="setActive()" data-id="tab2">select B</li>
</ol>
<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
<!--Your content-->
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
<!--Your content-->
</div>
```

you can use following jquery code :

```
$(".tabheader").click(function(){
    $(".tabcontent").hide();
    $("#"+$(this).data("id")).show();
});
```

To write inside the textarea from file server side you can use PHP or any other language which read file and put inside textarea. For that you can use file read function and call it between textarea.

Comment: Thank you @naitik but tried this on codepen https://codepen.io/noobcoderpk/pen/JjPQmYj  but all the tabs are showing without selecting it. I'll checkout for php to pull information from files thanks for the direction.

Comment: You forgot to add jquery in codepen. Also i thought you already hide the tabcontent at first. But you didnt so i did it for you.

Comment: https://codepen.io/naitik_kundalia/pen/rNBXpRr see this codepen